# R: aggregate combined with timeAverage

Tags: r, aggregate, plyr

I have a dataframe with hourly observed and modelled air quality data. Additional information is measuring station, country, stationtype and model:

```
> head(PM10val)
                 date station type   model country obs   mod
1 2009-01-01 00:00:00 BELAB01   sB chimere      BE  63 13.45
2 2009-01-01 01:00:00 BELAB01   sB chimere      BE  50 18.71
3 2009-01-01 02:00:00 BELAB01   sB chimere      BE  77 20.65
4 2009-01-01 03:00:00 BELAB01   sB chimere      BE  68 21.42
5 2009-01-01 04:00:00 BELAB01   sB chimere      BE  58 22.47
6 2009-01-01 05:00:00 BELAB01   sB chimere      BE  62 24.02
```

I would like to use the timeAverage function (calculate time-averages of a dataframe containing a date field) of openair package to calculate daily or annual mean values, per station and per model. I tried:

```
> anmean <- aggregate(PM10val, by=list(PM10val$station,PM10val$model),
+         function (x) timeAverage(x,avg.time="year",data.thresh=75,    statistic="mean"))
```

This should calculate annual mean averages for "obs" and "mod" per model and station, with a data capture threshold of 75%.
but it returns:

```
 Error in `[.default`(mydata, , Names) : incorrect number of dimensions
    11 NextMethod("[") 
10 `[.POSIXct`(mydata, , Names) 
9 mydata[, Names] 
8 checkPrep(mydata, vars, type = "default", remove.calm = FALSE, 
    strip.white = FALSE) 
7 timeAverage(x, avg.time = "year", data.thresh = 75, statistic = "mean") 
6 FUN(X[[1L]], ...) 
5 lapply(X = split(e, grp), FUN = FUN, ...) 
4 FUN(X[[1L]], ...) 
3 lapply(x, function(e) {
    ans <- lapply(X = split(e, grp), FUN = FUN, ...)
    if (simplify && length(len <- unique(sapply(ans, length))) == 
    1L) { ... 
2 aggregate.data.frame(PM10val, by = list(PM10val$station, PM10val$model), 
    function(x) timeAverage(x, avg.time = "year", data.thresh = 75, 
        statistic = "mean")) 
1 aggregate(PM10val, by = list(PM10val$station, PM10val$model), 
    function(x) timeAverage(x, avg.time = "year", data.thresh = 75, 
        statistic = "mean"))
```

What am I doing wrong? I can always use a loop but I don't think this is the way to go.
Thanks!

Comment: What does exactly `timeAverage(PM10val ,avg.time="year",data.thresh=75,    statistic="mean")` return? Also, after error please provide result of `traceback()`.

Comment: I added it in my main question above. Sorry for the confusement, this is the first time I ask a question !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use `ddply` instead. There are some issues with `POSIXct` data type and `aggregate`. In fact your function see `x` as a date, not a sub data.frame.

Following code works with Belgian data.
Function `ddply` does the same, it splits by levels you specify as a second parameter `c("site", "country")`, first will be split by "site" and then by "country", and then apply function for every split. I have wrapped your function to `Funfun` just to make code shorter. Also technicality is `bind_rows = rbind.fill` just set for binding data in importAirbase function. You can replace `data2` with your data and it should work.

```
library(plyr)
Funfun = function (x) timeAverage(x, avg.time="year", data.thresh=75, statistic="mean")
bind_rows = rbind.fill
data2 = importAirbase(site = c("BELAB01","BELAB02") , year = 2011:2012, pollutant = NA,
    add = c("country", "site.type"), splice = FALSE, local = NA)
ddply(data2, c("site", "country"), Funfun)
```

Comment: I just did. However, a small remark: the option "data.tresh=75" does not seem to work. There are stations with less than 6750 valid hourly data, and an annual mean is still calculated. Strange

Comment: @SandyAdriaenssens, does it work without `ddply`? with `timeAverage(data2, avg.time="year", data.thresh=75, statistic="mean")`. There is a way out, you can filter within function you apply with ddply.  Just add line with `x <- subset(x, mod < 75)` before line with `timeAverage`

Comment: Problem solved: it should be "data.thresh" instead of "data.tresh". Just forgot the letter "h". Apparently this gives no error, but is just ignored!